# PyOpenGL: glDrawArrays() - WindowsError: exception: access violation reading 0x0000000000000000

Tags: python, opengl, pyqt, vbo, pyopengl

I am having problems with `PyOpenGL` function `glDrawArrays()` when drawing VBO. I have an object (class) `ContactGeometry` and I create VBO with method `create_VBO()` and display VBO with method `paintGL_VBO()`:

```
class ContactGeometry(object):
    def __init__(self, _area=None, body=None, filename=None, uP=None, parent=None):
        ...
        self.VBO_created = False

    def create_VBO(self):
        if not self.VBO_created:
            #    generate a new VBO and get the associated vbo_id
            num_of_VBOs = 1
            #    create buffer name
            self.vbo_id = GLuint()
            self.vbo_id = glGenBuffers(num_of_VBOs)
            #    bind name to buffer
            glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.vbo_id)
            self.vbo_data = np.hstack((self.contact_nodes))
            self.N = len(self.contact_nodes)
            self.vbo_data = np.array(self.vbo_data, dtype='float32').flatten()
            #    VBO_data size in bytes
            self.VBO_data_size_in_bytes = arrays.ArrayDatatype.arrayByteCount(self.vbo_data)
            #    add VBO data to buffer
            glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.VBO_data_size_in_bytes, self.vbo_data, GL_STATIC_DRAW)
            self.VBO_created = True

    def paintGL_VBO(self):
        if self._visible and self.VBO_created:
            glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, self.vbo_id)
            #   pointers
            v_pointer = ctypes.c_void_p(0
            #    stride in bits (1 float = 4 bits)
            stride_in_bits = 0
            glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, stride_in_bits, v_pointer)
            glDisable(GL_LIGHTING)
            glDrawArrays(GL_LINE_STRIP,  0, self.N)
            glEnable(GL_LIGHTING)
            glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0)
```

The problem is that the program runs OK on platform with properties:

```
PyOpenGL_version = 3.1.0a1
GL Version: 4.2.12217 Compatibility Profile Context 12.104.0.0
GL Vendor: ATI Technologies Inc.
GL Renderer: AMD Radeon HD 6300M Series
```

But NOT OK on platform with properties:

```
PyOpenGL_version = 3.0.2
GL Version: 4.3.0
GL Vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
GL Renderer: Quadro 600/PCIe/SSE2
```

As it returns the following error:

```
WindowsError: exception: access violation reading 0x0000000000000000
```

Any ideas how to fix this as I would like to run the code on multiple platforms (with different GPU). It is very irrational as the code works on older version software, but not on newer version...

In `init()` of class `OpenGLWidget` I set:

```
class OpenGLWidget(QtOpenGL.QGLWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        ...
        # core profile
        glformat = QtOpenGL.QGLFormat()
        glformat.setProfile(QtOpenGL.QGLFormat.CompatibilityProfile)
```

Comment: Check if self.contact_nodes is properly allocated. The error you're getting suggests you're trying to read the value of a null pointer.

Comment: @Xirema if I print the pointer to `self.contact_nodes` right data is printed. Also if I run `glIsBuffer(self.vbo_id)` on both platforms it returns `1`.

Comment: Assign 'length' as a variable on a previous line before glDrawArrays(), like so: "int length = len(self.contact_nodes)" then use "glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, length)" Let me know if this changes the location of the error or not.

Comment: I was trying this couple of minutes ago, as I said I succesfully paint 3D triangular meshes and there I input lenght as object attribute something like `self.N`. Allthough here without any succes. Could you maybe look at the entire code? I also added the entire class where I build and paint VBO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have found a problem and solved it... The problem was that I have enabled normal pointer:

```
glEnableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY)
```

but have not defined any normal pointer. The solution is to dissable normal pointer:

```
glDisableClientState(GL_NORMAL_ARRAY)
```

or to add pointer to normal like:

```
glNormalPointer(GL_FLOAT, 0, ctypes.c_void_p(0))
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like glEnableClientState is deprecated in modern versions of OpenGL. The AMD card is definitely giving you a Compatibility Profile, which means it won't care if you try to use deprecated functionality, but the NVidia card isn't indicating whether your profile is Core or Compatibility. You should make sure your code is expressly requesting a Compatibility Profile.

Comment: Please see the main question as I added the code where I set the Profile and the problem is not fixed. I forgot to say that with mainly the same code logic I display 3D triangular meshes without a problem. But I am having problems with this...